# Stat data member error

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" {
#include "dimacs_reader.h"
}


struct boolean{
        int numvar;
        int numclause;
        int clause[numclause][numvar];
};

boolean *clauseptr;
int clauseindex;

void init(int numvars, int numclauses) {
        // Callback function that gets passed to read_dimacs().
        // Indicates start of a new expression with up to numvars variables
        // and numclauses clauses.

        clauseptr = new boolean;
        clauseptr->numvar=numvars;
        clauseptr->numclause=numclauses;
        clauseptr->clause[numclauses][numvars];
        clauseindex=0;


}

void add_clause(int numlits, int literals[]) {
        // Callback function that gets passed to read_dimacs().
        // The literals argument is an array of ints, numlits is its length.
        // Each literal is the index (starting from 1) of a variable.
        // Negative integers represent logical negations of variables.

        clauseptr->clause[clauseindex][numlits];
        for(int i=0; i<numlits ; i++){
                clauseptr->clause[clauseindex][i] = literals[i];
        }
        clauseindex++;


}
char *classify() {
    // Evaluate the current expression and return one of
    // "satisfiable", "unsatisfiable" or "tautology".
    return (char *) "unsatisfiable";
```

}

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
                read_dimacs(argv[i], init, add_clause);
                printf("%s: %s\n", argv[i], classify());
        }
        return 0;
```

}

I get an error saying numvar and numclause which are in the boolean struct are static data members. I am trying to use the 2 ints and array in my struct to store some data using my init function. Am i using the pointer incorrectly? 
My init and add_clause function use a function called read_dimacs to parse through a .cnf file, and the function also uses the init and add_clause functions as parameters.

this is my full error message:

```
main.cpp:15:13: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘boolean::numclause’
         int numclause;
             ^
main.cpp:16:20: error: from this location
         int clause[numclause][numvar];
                    ^
main.cpp:14:13: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘boolean::numvar’
         int numvar;
             ^
main.cpp:16:31: error: from this location
         int clause[numclause][numvar];
                               ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void init(int, int)’:
main.cpp:30:13: error: ‘struct boolean’ has no member named ‘clause’
  clauseptr->clause[numclauses][numvars];
             ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void add_clause(int, int*)’:
main.cpp:42:13: error: ‘struct boolean’ has no member named ‘clause’
  clauseptr->clause[clauseindex][numlits];
             ^
main.cpp:44:14: error: ‘struct boolean’ has no member named ‘clause’
   clauseptr->clause[clauseindex][i] = literals[i];
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error message?

Comment: `int clause[numclause][numvar];` is not valid C++ - you need compile-time constants to specify array size(s)

Comment: 1. smart pointers.  They're your friend and you should use them if you can rather than raw pointers

Comment: 2. a global pointer that you create once may as well just be on the stack;  no need to use new at all

Comment: @UnholySheep then how else can i initialize my array in the struct? if I cannot use those variables?

Comment: `std::vector` is your friend.

Comment: @NathanOliver i am doing a project, for which I am not allowed to use std::vector

Comment: Also **never** do `return (char *) "unsatisfiable";`.  Your breaking const correctness and making your code harder to reason about.

Comment: Note that error messages can span multiple lines.  Yes, the first error says `invalid use of non-static data member`, but the next message is really the key: `from this location`.  You can't use a non-static data member as the array size (a.k.a. variable-length arrays) without enabling compiler extensions.  Look into `std::vector` instead.

Comment: if you can't use std::vector; you want to use new on the creation of the array; not in the creation of your struct; as this is how you can have a variable sized array

Comment: @NathanOliver so many friends missing from this party ;)